# I get "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent" when I change my theme

Tags: php, css

I get this error when I change theme in my wordpress.
*Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mortgage/public_html/autoblogdemon.com/test/wp-content/plugins/test/test.php:28) in /home/mortgage/public_html/autoblogdemon.com/test/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 866*

Notice output started ar test.php:28

here is test.php and line 28 is the second opening

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: test
Plugin URI: 
Description: is about to leave the page. make sure you check out the demo of the plugin.
Author: Ronny Kibet
Author URI: 
version: 1.0
*/

//html begins here.
function my_text_on_top(){

?>

<!-- bar starts here -->
<div id="bar">hi there </div>


<?php // line 28 starts here.

}
add_action('init','my_text_on_top');
```

the plugin works fine by showing a "hi there" text inside of the div with id "bar".

can somone help me get rid of the error and be able to change my themes when I activate the plugin.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your plugin should not be outputting anything to the browser on `init`. As you can see by the error, some code in `pluggable.php` is trying to set a header, but headers were already sent when your plugin sent output. If you want to output markup, you have to hook something in the page body, like [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer).

Comment: @Ronny - `wp_head` is fired before the opening body tag, so outputting markup there may have unpredictable results depending on the browser.